# Display SVG in IE8

Tags: javascript, wordpress, svg, internet-explorer-8

I have a WordPress site with lots of custom fields that contain images in .svg format.
Now I want to add support to IE8, which won't display SVG, so I need to find a solution.

The first thing I think of is to add custom fields to add a .png along with every .svg on the site, but this means to go through each and every custom fields to modify them...

I've also seen that there's a library called Raphael.js that supports IE, but it's intended to draw the SVGs, and I already have many complex SVGs created with Illustrator, so this is not a solution for me...

Is there any way (i.e. JS library) that, each time you want to load a SVG with:

```
<img src="http://mydomain/Homepage-1.svg" alt="Image Alt">
```

it automatically converts it to plain image?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/svg2vml/

Comment: IE8 doesn't support SVG, but there are a number of polyfill libraries that can fix that for you (usually by converting it to VML, which is an IE-proprietary vector format supported by IE6/7/8). [See here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#svg) for a list of available polyfills.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/svgweb/

Answer (score 0):

You can include a call for Adobe's SVG Viewer for IE8
see:
http://www.iegallery.com/en-us/Addons/Details/444

It still works nicely for svg including filters.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe  SVG Viewer was discontinued in 2009. I still have clients from time to time that have need of support for IE8. This page has a few polyfills worth trying:

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#svg

You'll need to decide what you want your fallback to be, Flash, Canvas, Silverlight, and then choose the right solution for you.